# Xubuntu notification menu is randomly empty

Tags: xubuntu, notification

I'm testing out Xubuntu in VMware before I commit to it, and I noticed the notifications menu is <s>always</s> sometimes empty. I run a test, e.g. `notify-send Title 'This is a message.'`, and I can see the notification pop up. I ignore it, waiting for it to disappear, and then when I check the menu, it's sometimes empty:

[image]

How do I get this working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

OS: Xubuntu 18.04

- Click on the notification bell icon
- Turn off "Do not disturb"
- Then, in *Notification settings …*, open the *Log* tab, and set *Log notifications* to *always* and *Log applications* to *all*.

General Tab

[image: General]

---

Applications Tab

[image: Applications]

---

Log Tab

[image: Log]

---

Notifcation bell icon dropdown

[image: Bell icon]

Comment: Strange, it didn't work for a moment. But now, randomly, it does. https://imgur.com/q2x7iaS (this is from when it wasn't working)

Comment: Actually, it works sporadically, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: If you had mentioned the random nature of the issue, I wouldn't have posted an answer. I answered because there was no indication of the issue being sporadic.

Comment: I didn't realize it was sporadic until going through these steps.